# Yii2 disable every fields label from activeform

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I want to disable all the label of activeform fields but my code is not working

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableLabel'=>false]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'modeid')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'projectid')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'projecttype')->textInput() ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Comment: Use like this: `<?= $form->field($model, 'sample_text')->textArea()->label(false) ?>`

Comment: In Yii2 there is no settings for disable label in one time..??

Comment: No, there are no property with `enableLabel`

Answer (score 4):

There is no property `enableLabel` in ActiveForm.

If you want to remove labels from the field widgets add

```
->label(false)
```

after `->textInput()`.

Comment: Clear universal solution for to disabled label for particular field

Answer (score 4):

You should use `fieldConfig` from `ActiveForm` to do this:

```
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['fieldConfig' => ['enableLabel'=>false]]); ?>
```

Comment: Error is " Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ActiveField::enableLabel "

Comment: Are you using `yii\widgets\ActiveForm` or `yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm`? If `widgets` -> change it to `bootstrap`.

Comment: Yes done working just i also researching there and get solved the error..thanx Yupik

Answer (score 0):

I found another option.
In your model class. public function attributeLabels().
Set your properties labels to empty strings.

```
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'modeid'    => '',
        'projectid' => '',
        'projecttype' => '',
    ];
}
```

Comment: This will still render label, but with empty text.

Comment: I did not thought about that. Thanks for the clarification.